# An asp.net connection string have been encoded

Tags: asp.net, encoding, connection-string, decoding

I have an an .aspx file in an .NET 4 application that i cant access its source code, it generates the following html\javascript lines of code:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function SaveImage(){
    APP1.MyNAME.ConnectionString = 'fopwigdlgbksrgptiwpgskddgsgerqwwvdmsftapsdarqewfldszvkzlvkglkazxxcvlbmfkhpoiejkgjksdlfkldkajfakkglkdgpsggedtzxsadlklglpwriuqtjvnvkiweurqiwjfkdvbnbjeowqewptyiogxlmbxjgbortwoiqerpqiwioitowiyowiskblskogtiwotiwptqipvkvzlvkzalqpreppoypehlxbklsitpqrqprfkvzlvkpwroqproqpopazkvkzvzitwptipwtpwsop'
    APP1.MYNAME.ConnectionOpen()=
    APP1.MYNAME.SaveToDB(

    ...
</script>
```

Someone has decoded the above ConnectionString to the:

```
server=localhost;uid=XXXXXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXXXXX;database=XXXXXXXXXXXX;Min Pool Size=5;Maz pool Size=100;Connect timeout=15;;Workstation ID=1
```

I want to know what decoding and encoding algorithm may have been used here and what tool can be used for encoding or decoding in the above senario...

Thx

Comment: Please refer 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Cipher Values that have been generated in this article are somethings like "AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAH2..." but in my case contains only small letters "fopwigdlgbksrgptiwpgskddgsgerq...."